# AWS CloudFormation: AMI in LaunchConfiguration was deleted

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

As the title says, I have a `CFN` stack that uses a `LaunchConfiguration` for EC2.  The config gets the AMI-id from a Lambda function that looks up the latest AMI for a particular type.  This is very similar to what's described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html)

The AMI that was used in creating the launch-config has been deleted.  When I try to update the stack I get an expected error:

```
UPDATE_FAILED   AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration   ECSLaunchConfiguration  AMI cannot be described
```

I cannot delete the stack, so is there any way to resolve this using `CFN`.  A new AMI is out there, so how I get `CFN` to re-create the config by re-running the Lambda function?

Comment: The simplest way to have CloudFormation re-run the lambda would be to set a parameter on the custom resource that you aren't using, such as `RandomValue: 4`. CloudFormation assumes that everything is stateless, so if the parameters to any resource don't change, then the result should be identical. You need to add some uniqueness to the AMI lookup, because overtime the result of the lookup will change.

Comment: I agree with @JamieStarke, although I use the `Serial` instead of `RandomValue`. This is inspired by how `AWS::IAM::AccessKey` is rotated (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-accesskey.html). Finally, I would encourage you to have the process of finding the latest AMI in a pre-process instead of fetching this at runtime. This will allow you to have trully replicable stacks.